# Unable to return http.clent getresponse() object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to pass the HTTPResponse object from a called function back to the caller.

```
def caller():
    r = called()
    with open('/some/file/', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.read())


def called():
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('/some/host',
                                       'some port',
                                       'some ssl.Context')
    conn.request('GET', '/some/url', {'some': 'headers'})
    r = conn.getresponse()
    conn.close()
    return r
```

When doing the above, it creates the file, but nothing writes. However, if I do the following:

```
def caller():
    r = called()
    with open('/some/file/', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r)


def called():
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('/some/host',
                                       'some port',
                                       'some ssl.Context')
    conn.request('GET', '/some/url', {'some': 'headers'})
    r = conn.getresponse()
    c = r.read()
    conn.close()
    return c
```

It executes fine with appropriate returns and writes to file. The latter is not ideal as I need to call `conn.close()` to force server connections to terminate.

**Question:**

> Why can I not return a `getresponse()` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in the first case you are calling

```
conn.close()
```

And THEN reading from it.

Comment: Even if I get rid of `conn.close()`, once I `return r` it's as though the object is now NULL.

Comment: OK. I don't have Python3 to test it, but what I would do next is add a print statement before the f.write line to see if it gets executed. If it does, I would add another one to see what r.read() returns.